# NodeJS how to read from /dev/pts/1

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to read from /dev/pts/1 with nodeJS?
If i cat /dev/pts/1 i can see data.

I tryed to use this :

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/dev/pts/1', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data);
});
```

This give no output.
And also no error.

[Image of running the script with no output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqq7K.png)

Comment: `console.log(err)` and show which error are you getting.

Comment: I have change code and run the script no luck no output from err and data. Have also put picture in when i run the script.

Comment: Have a look at https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream When you `cat` the device, does it return to the terminal, or does it wait for you to break?

Comment: When i cat i get data stream and need to break it to stop.